# How do I connect this string of LEDs to my Arduino Uno?

Tags: led

I'm an electronics noob. I have this string of LEDs but don't know how to connect them to my Arduino Uno. As they are wired in parallel, there are two wires / four ends. What do I plug where?

[image: string of LEDS]

Comment: How many LEDs are in the string?  How much current is the string of LEDs supposed to take?  What voltage are they rated at?  What model number, or do you have a spec sheet we can look at?

Answer (score 1):

Connect the negative ( or cathode ) to ground ( 0V )
and the postive ( anode ) to the output pin of the controller.

Firstly connecting that many LEDS directly to a single micro pin is not a good idea. Usually you would need to go through a buffer/driver first which can deliver the correct power to the LEDS.

I'm not that familiar with the UNO but unless that board has a driver circuit on it you might need a few extra components.

[image: Basic LED driver]

What are the specs of the LEDS?

Comment: Just to be clear. The resistor isn't necessarily on the anode (+) side of the leds (as shown in the diagram). To easily figure out, which is which, plug one end in the 5v pin and the other in the GND pin. If they don't light up, swap the ends around. The end placed in the 5v is the anode(+).